# ReDim to List<T> in C#

Tags: c#, vb6

The way I understand, Redim is similar to `List<T>`.  I can use help ensuring a proper conversion from this VB6 to C#:

```
Private Sub ParseString(sInput As String, sWords() As String, lCount As Long, sDel As String)      
    '   Parses a delimited input string (sInput) on a single
    '   delimiter and returns the parsed words back in a
    '   string array sWords().
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    '
    ' INPUTS:
    '   sInput - string to be parsed.
    '   sDel   - Delimiter character.
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' OUTPUTS:
    '   sWords() - dynamic string array containing the parsed words.
    '
    '   lCount   - long, returning the number of words parsed
    '
    ' NOTES:
    '   If this subroutine is passed an empty string, it will
    '   return a lCount of 0 with one element in sWords().
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Dim lWordStart As Long
    Dim lWordEnd As Long
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim lParsedArraySize As Long
    Dim lDelLen As Long
    '    Dim lStartM As Long
    '    Dim lEndM As Long
    Dim lLength As Long

    lDelLen = Len(sDel)
    lLength = Len(sInput)

    If sInput = "" Then
       ReDim sWords(1 To 1) As String
       lCount = 0
       sWords(1) = ""
       Exit Sub
    End If
    lParsedArraySize = 50
ReDim sWords(1 To lParsedArraySize) As String

    lWordStart = 1
    lCount = 1

    Do
        lWordEnd = InStr(lWordStart, sInput, sDel)
        If lWordEnd = 0 Then
            sTemp = Mid$(sInput, lWordStart)

            If lCount > lParsedArraySize Then
            ReDim Preserve sWords(1 To lCount) As String
            End If
            sWords(lCount) = sTemp
            Exit Do
        Else
            sTemp = Mid$(sInput, lWordStart, lWordEnd - lWordStart)
            'If sTemp <> "" Then
            If lCount > lParsedArraySize Then
                lParsedArraySize = lParsedArraySize + 50
                ReDim Preserve sWords(1 To lParsedArraySize) As String
            End If
            sWords(lCount) = sTemp
            lCount = lCount + 1
            'End If
            lWordStart = lWordEnd + lDelLen
        End If
    Loop

    If lCount < lParsedArraySize Then
    ReDim Preserve sWords(1 To lCount) As String
    End If
```

How should I convert this If statement to C#?  So far I have...

```
private void ParseString(string sInput, List<string> sWords, int lCount, string sDel)
{
    int lWordStart;
    int lWordEnd;
    string sTemp;
    int lParsedArraySize;
    int lDelLen;
    //int lStartM;
    //int lEndM;
    int lLength;

    lDelLen = sDel.Length;

     lLength = sInput.Length;

    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(sInput))
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: `foreach(String current in sWords){ ... }`

Comment: @AndreCalil `sWords` is supposed to be filled by `ParseString`. `foreach` on an empty list won't do much.

Comment: @AndreCalil - Where are you coming up with `foreach`?  I don't understand why we have `Exit Sub` in this if statement...is there a loop here somehow...?

Comment: I'm sorry guys, I hadn't get the point of the method. I thought you only needed help to figure out how to iterate at that list.

Comment: Ah-hah!  Your additional code helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function call appears to be modifying the array.  If so, here's what you'd need to do:

EDIT: Now that you provided some additional detail, I think you need two outputs.

```
private void ParseString(string sInput, out List<string> sWords, out int lCount, string sDel)
{
    int lWordStart;
    int lWordEnd;
    string sTemp;
    int lParsedArraySize;
    int lDelLen;
    int lLength;

    lDelLen = sDel.Length;

    lLength = sInput.Length;

    // We are required to set all the output values in this function call    
    sWords = new List<string>();
    lCount = 0;

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(sInput)) {
        sWords.Add(""); // Now, sWords[0] will equal "" - this may not be exactly what
        // your VB code expects, but since all C# arrays begin with zero it's the
        // closest approximation.  Alternatively, you could add two items so that
        // sWords[1] would still return the correct value.
        return;
    }
    lParsedArraySize = 50;

    // I'm assuming there's more code down here that does more work ;)
}
```

Comment: I think this may be close, but that `Exit sub` is not accounted for.  Perhaps the if statement just needs `return sWords;`

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey `Sub` in VB are like `void` return methods in C-Sharp, so it would just be `return;`.

Comment: Also, it doesn't seem like `lParsedArraySize` is used, so you can just remove it, infact, the majority of those variables aren't used.

Comment: I'm assuming PBM omitted a lot of the actual string parsing code for readability.

Comment: @Matthew There might be more to the routine than has been displayed.  We shouldn't assume that the variables aren't used. The `Exit Sub` is inside a conditional.

Answer (score 0):

`ReDim` is not the same as `List`.  `ReDim` allows you to modify the size of an array.  This allows you to *emulate the variable size behavior of a list* with an array using `ReDim`.

It looks like your logic is testing whether the input is empty and assigning that value to the first output element.  It also seems to be clearing the list (array) first. One way to do that would be this:

```
if (sWords == null) {
  sWords = new List<string>(); // Ensure the list is not null
}
else {
  sWords.Clear()      // Clear the list if it was provided
} 

// Add an empty string to the list if the input was empty.
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(sInput)) {
  sWords.Add(String.Empty);
  return;
}
```